# How to create a pivot in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

How can I convert the below query into a pivot format? i need ship date as rows tracking id as values and shp, sxm as columns, i just added the format at the end of query appreciate if someone can let me know how i can get all this into pivot format, i am really new into this so i would love if someone can convert my query into pivot instead of any reference.

Comment: Formatting of the results makes them easier to comprehend -- you'll want to do some more work as I'm not sure which text is the column and which is the data for some of the columns (e.g. all other than `Scan_Date`).

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? If < 11g, then you'll want to use conditional aggregation to pivot. If 11g or greater, you might be better off using the `PIVOT` function.

Comment: i am using <11g can you plz let me know how i can use cond. agg to pivot?

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
with a as (
  select ship_date, 
      case -- <- modify this part
        when tracking_id like 'Q%' then 'Q' 
        else 'N' end 
      category,  
      seen_at_SP1_sort_scan shp1, 
      seen_at_sm1_sort_scan sxm1, 
      seen_at_ds_scan sds1
    from test  -- <- your inner query goes here
  )
select ship_date,
    count(decode(category, 'Q', shp1)) shp1_a,
    count(decode(category, 'N', shp1)) shp1_n,
    count(decode(category, 'Q', sxm1)) sxm1_a,
    count(decode(category, 'N', sxm1)) sxm1_n,
    count(decode(category, 'Q', sds1)) sds1_a,
    count(decode(category, 'N', sds1)) sds1_n,
    count(decode(category, 'Q', 1)) total_a,
    count(decode(category, 'N', 1)) total_n
  from a group by ship_date order by ship_date
```

Results:

```
SHIP_DATE   SHP1_A SHP1_N SXM1_A SXM1_N SDS1_A SDS1_N TOTAL_A TOTAL_N
----------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------- -------
2015-03-09       1      0      2      0      0      0       3       0
2015-03-10       2      2      2      4      0      1       3       4
2015-03-11       0      0      1      0      1      0       1       0
2015-03-12       2      0      0      0      0      0       2       0
```

Instead of `test` put your inner query, this starting with `SELECT o.carrier_ref_number...`. 
Modify part for `category` according to your needs, it's not clear what you want here.
Use `case when...` instead of `decode(category...` if your criteria are more complicated.

If you have Oracle 11g or newer you can experiment with [pivot](http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php).

---

**Edit:** modified, full queries for Oracle 11 (pivoted) and for prior versions. 
Please replace '20150312' near bottom with your parameter `{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}` as in your query.

For Oracle 11:

```
select ship_date, a_shp1 shp1_a, n_shp1 shp1_n, a_sxm1 sxm1_a, n_sxm1 sxm1_n,
    a_shp1+a_sxm1 total_a, n_shp1+n_sxm1 total_n 
  from (
    with ships as (
      select ship_date, category, shp1, sxm1
        from (
          SELECT o.carrier_ref_number tracking_id, o.pkg_manifest_run_date ship_date,
              CASE WHEN (o.carrier_ref_number) LIKE 'Q%' 
                THEN 'A' -- AMZL
                ELSE 'N' -- Non-AMZL
              END Category,
              (SELECT min(transport_shipment_status_date) 
                FROM transport_shipments ts 
                  JOIN transport_shipment_statuses tss 
                    ON tss.transport_shipment_id=ts.transport_shipment_id 
                WHERE ts.carrier_ref_number=o.carrier_ref_number 
                  AND tss.ship_status='X4' AND tss.status_node_id='SHP1'
              ) shp1,   --seen_at_SHP1_sort_scan,
              (SELECT min(transport_shipment_status_date) 
                FROM transport_shipments ts 
                  JOIN transport_shipment_statuses tss 
                    ON tss.transport_shipment_id=ts.transport_shipment_id 
                WHERE ts.carrier_ref_number=o.carrier_ref_number 
                  AND tss.ship_status='X4' AND tss.status_node_id='SXM1'
              ) sxm1   -- seen_at_SXM1_sort_scan
            FROM otm_ob_cust_pkg_records o 
            WHERE o.pkg_manifest_run_date 
              BETWEEN to_date('20150312', 'YYYYMMDD') - 10 
                  AND to_date('20150312', 'YYYYMMDD')
          ) A 
        where shp1 is not null or sxm1 is not null)
    select * from ships
      pivot (count(shp1) as shp1, count(sxm1) as sxm1
        for (category) IN ('A' AS a, 'N' AS n))
  ) order by ship_date
```

For older Oracle version:

```
select ship_date, 
    sum(decode(category, 'A', shp1)) shp1_a,
    sum(decode(category, 'N', shp1)) shp1_n,
    sum(decode(category, 'A', sxm1)) sxm1_a, 
    sum(decode(category, 'N', sxm1)) sxm1_n,
    sum(decode(category, 'A', shp1)) + sum(decode(category, 'A', sxm1)) total_a,
    sum(decode(category, 'N', shp1)) + sum(decode(category, 'N', sxm1)) total_n
  from (
    SELECT A.ship_date,
      CASE WHEN (A.tracking_id) LIKE 'Q%' THEN 'A' ELSE 'N' END Category,
      COUNT(seen_at_SHP1_sort_scan) shp1, COUNT(seen_at_SXM1_sort_scan) sxm1
    from (
      select o.carrier_ref_number tracking_id, o.pkg_manifest_run_date ship_date,      
          (SELECT min(transport_shipment_status_date) FROM transport_shipments ts JOIN transport_shipment_statuses tss ON tss.transport_shipment_id=ts.transport_shipment_id WHERE ts.carrier_ref_number=o.carrier_ref_number AND tss.ship_status='X4' AND tss.status_node_id='SHP1') seen_at_SHP1_sort_scan,
          (SELECT min(transport_shipment_status_date) FROM transport_shipments ts JOIN transport_shipment_statuses tss ON tss.transport_shipment_id=ts.transport_shipment_id WHERE ts.carrier_ref_number=o.carrier_ref_number AND tss.ship_status='X4' AND tss.status_node_id='SXM1') seen_at_SXM1_sort_scan
        FROM otm_ob_cust_pkg_records o 
        WHERE o.pkg_manifest_run_date BETWEEN to_date('20150312', 'YYYYMMDD') - 10 AND to_date('20150312', 'YYYYMMDD')
      ) A 
    WHERE A.seen_at_SHP1_sort_scan IS NOT NULL OR A.seen_at_SXM1_sort_scan IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY A.ship_date, a.tracking_id)
  group by ship_date order by ship_date
```

You may want to use `nvl(..., 0)` for summing columns, for instance: `nvl(sum(decode(category, 'A', shp1)), 0) shp1_a`.

Test results for both queries:

```
  SHIP_DATE   SHP1_A    SHP1_N   SXM1_A   SXM1_N   TOTAL_A  TOTAL_N
  ----------  -------   -------  -------  -------  -------  -------
  2015-03-11        0         1        0        1        0        2
  2015-03-12        1         0        1        0        2        0
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the above i just edited my query with the format can you plz advise?

Comment: I will try, please check for some time.

Comment: I managed to do it. Hope it will work for you. See EDIT section.

Comment: thanks for above for some reason its still giving me almost 1400 rows of data dates are getting appeared more than once, result is not appearing as you showed in above example, so should we change count with sum?

Comment: I suspect missing grouping by tracking_id, try last query. Changing to sum will not work. What you mean by _result is not appearing as you showed in above example_ ? You did not attach any input data so I put some test values. Also - I do not count that: `seen_at_ds_scan` because in your original query you did not want it. Instead is sum of first columns. Changing it is simple, but it's not clear what should be done.

Comment: what i mean is when i am not using the pivot i am having 801000 Q for seen at shp1 but with pivot i am only having 5000 q make sense?

Comment: Please check modified last query, you were probably right about sums. It's hard to verify without real data access.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the SQL PIVOT function

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Example (from reference page):

```
select * from (
   select times_purchased as "Puchase Frequency", state_code
   from customers t
)
pivot 
(
   count(state_code)
   for state_code in ('NY' as "New York",'CT' "Connecticut",'NJ' "New Jersey",'FL' "Florida",'MO' as "Missouri")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it appears you are missing a final closing ") alias" to finish the FROM clause.  You have...

```
FROM ( select statement... ending with 
          columnQuery seen_at_SM1_sort_scan...
```

need

```
FROM ( select statement... ending with 
          columnQuery seen_at_SM1_sort_scan... ) SQLResult
```

Next, you have no Group By which is the basis of a pivot to show aggregations per a specific element...  At best, you would need

```
GROUP BY
    A.ship_date
   ,CASE A.tracking_id
       WHEN FIRST(A.tracking_id) = Q
           THEN AM
           ELSE Non - AM
           END
```

Finally, showing some sample data of what you are ultimately hoping to get could help, even if it is fake data... and do NOT use TABs in the sample output for formatting as tabs don't always format well.